# Menu conflict with border-bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to include a border-bottom-image (the arrow, 159px width).
Like this:

[image]

But the problem is, that the `<li>` can't get a width of 159px.

[image]

There are any tricks to represent the border image, without push the other `<li>` away?

lg cgee

The code of the `<li>`:

```
.sub_menu ul li {
    float: left;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 41px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

The code of the active element:

```
.sub_menu ul .active {
    background-image: url("../images/sub_menu_border_active.png");
    background-position: center 17px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to post code to reproduce your issue or the question will just get closed.

Comment: I did it .. I include a third picture too.

Comment: You could also try using CSS3 shapes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possibilities for you to achieve desired result:

1. You can add `min-width: 159px` to li.
2. You can add additional element in `li` (e.g. `span`) with `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0`. You would need to add `overflow: visible` to `li` as well.
3. Below:

**CSS**

```
.sub_menu ul .active {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
    overflow: visible;
}

.sub_menu ul .active:after {
    content: '';
    background-image: url("../images/sub_menu_border_active.png");
    background-position: center 17px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
    height: ...;
    width: 159px;
    z-index: 101;
}
```

Comment: 1. works, but not my goal :/ 2. don't work?! ...

Comment: `<li class="active">
<a href="technology/google-analytics/">Google Analytics</a>
<span class="sub_menu_arrow"></span>
</li>` 

The class:

`.sub_menu_arrow {
    background-image: url("../images/sub_menu_border_active.png");
    background-position: center 17px;
    bottom: -4px;
    display: block;
    height: 19px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -75px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 160px;
}`